# SQL Server 2000 equivalent of GROUP_CONCAT function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, string-aggregation

I tried to use the `GROUP_CONCAT` function in SQL Server 2000 but it returns an error:

> 'group_concat' is not a recognized function name"

So I guess there is an other function for `group_concat` in SQL Server 2000? Can you tell me what it is?

Comment: Do you mean mysql as in "your SQL" Because that's not really what that tag is for.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately since you are using SQL Server 2000 you cannot use `FOR XML PATH` to concatenate the values together.

Let's say we have the following sample Data:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable ([id] int, [name] varchar(4));

INSERT INTO yourtable ([id], [name])
VALUES (1, 'John'), (1, 'Jim'),
    (2, 'Bob'), (3, 'Jane'), (3, 'Bill'), (4, 'Test'), (4, '');
```

One way you could generate the list together would be to [create a function](http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-from-a-column-into-a-single-row.html).  A sample function would be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.List 
( 
    @id int
) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @r VARCHAR(8000) 
      SELECT @r = ISNULL(@r+', ', '') + name
      FROM dbo.yourtable 
      WHERE id = @id 
        and Name > ''  -- add filter if you think you will have empty strings
    RETURN @r 
END
```

Then when you query the data, you will pass a value into the function to concatenate the data into a single row:

```
select distinct id, dbo.list(id) Names
from yourtable;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22404/1). This gives you a result:

```
| ID |      NAMES |
-------------------
|  1 |  John, Jim |
|  2 |        Bob |
|  3 | Jane, Bill |
|  4 |       Test |
```

Comment: You should add another where clause criteria for Name > ''    This will protect you against nulls and empty strings, which would make the output either wrong or just plain weird.