# Concatenate rows to single row in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, monetdb, monetdblite

I'm using MonetDb for analytics, which is using SQL Server 2008 for query processing.

I have a table ROLES, which has data below.

```
Emp ROLE
1   ROLE_1
1   ROLE_2
1   ROLE_3
2   ROLE_1
2   ROLE_2
3   ROLE_3
3   ROLE_4
```

I want output as

```
EMP ROLE
1   ROLE_1, ROLE_2, ROLE_3
2   ROLE_1, ROLE_2
3   ROLE_3, ROLE_4
```

I tried group_concat, but it is saying

> no such aggregate 'group_concat'

Query I tried is below

```
select
    emp,
    group_concat(role) as wo
from 
    roles 
group by emp
```

Is there any alternative for `group_concat`?

**Edit:**

Please read comments, I'm using monetdb which doesn't support group_concat and xml.

Comment: See if this helps you: [how to make a query with group_concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried this also. I'm getting **syntax error, unexpected FOR, expecting SCOLON in**

Comment: @TT. I tried it. but not working tough. **select emp, role + ',' as role from roles FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql server 2000 the GROUP\_CONCAT() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618132/sql-server-2000-the-group-concat-function)

Comment: ...and if you're going to take your pick, pick 2017, because it has [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) :D

Comment: @marc_s: Actually it says 2008 but not behaving so. take a look https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/SQLreference

Comment: I can't understand Why people are down voting even before reading comments. I'm mentioning that I already tried all the links provided by you people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monetdb has R integration. You can write a R function.

[Check this link](https://www.monetdb.org/content/embedded-r-monetdb)

R function:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE str_aggre(val STRING) RETURNS STRING LANGUAGE R {
   aggregate(val, by=list(aggr_group), FUN=toString)$x 
};
```

SQL Command:

```
select
    emp,
    str_aggre(role) as wo
from 
    roles 
group by emp
```

This will work.

Comment: Thank you. I tried for R functions also. This helped me. You saved my day.